# testing cookies on flags

Tags: javascript, cookies, postman

I am trying to write some test in Postman App (Chrome ext.). I have a simple HTTP request:

```
GET /BusinessBanking/ HTTP/1.1
Host: www.mojebanka.cz
```

Two different cookies are returned, with different HTTP and Secure flags.

[cookie flags](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JKqEE.png)

Now I run these tests and all of them are passed:

```
tests ["cookie1 HTTP"] = postman.getResponseCookie("JSESSIONID").http = true;
tests ["cookie1 secure"] = postman.getResponseCookie("JSESSIONID").secure = true;
tests ["cookie2 HTTP"] = postman.getResponseCookie("language").http = true;
tests ["cookie2 secure"] = postman.getResponseCookie("language").secure = true;
```

So my question is, how to test both those cookies on HTTP and Secure flags?

Comment: I am not testing on values, I would like to test the cookies on HTTPonly and secure flags. I have changed all tests to `=== true` and all are now fails except second test. I have read something about JS inaccessibility of HTTPonly cookies, but I can easy run tests on their other flasgs (value, path, etc.); so I am not sure, what exactly means "httpOnly cookies are not accessible in JS"

Comment: in Postman app cookie flag designation (at least HTTP as httpOnly) seems to be wrong as well. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out, how to perform tests on HTTPonly and secure flags:

```
tests ["cookie1 HTTP"] = postman.getResponseCookie("JSESSIONID").httpOnly === true;
tests ["cookie1 secure"] = postman.getResponseCookie("JSESSIONID").secure === true;
tests ["cookie2 HTTP"] = postman.getResponseCookie("language").httpOnly === false;
tests ["cookie2 secure"] = postman.getResponseCookie("language").secure === false;
```

so, even HTTPonly (or httpOnly to be precise) cookies can be tested this way.